# Qestion about Linux Tails persistent volume

Tags: tails, linux

I'm trying out Tails and have been able to set up a persistent volume.
My question is: On a website I want to upload a document on a forum which obviously opens a window to browse my filesystem.

Again obviously I get the message "access denied" to both the persistent volume and also when I copy the file to the desktop. I say obviously because in a way it's a primairt security feature of Tails to not allow acccess.

Then again, how am I able to upload the document?

Answer (score 3):

It is really simple.

**Move file to be uploaded to**

```
~/Tor Browser  
PersistentDir/Tor Browser
```

These are the folders you can upload from or download to.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed simple (if you know the answer ;)) Strange there isn't more information to be found like a real comprehensive knowledgebase.

Comment: @Tailormade A good way to say Thank you is to upvote or to accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Will do in the future. Have upvoted, however cannot accept answer (yet?).